# Get cocoapods version in post_install

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is it possible to know which version of cocoapods is installed, in post_install of the Podfile? I would like to add two config settings if cocoapods version is 1.5

```
post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if target.name === 'AlamofireImage'
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.3'
            end
            config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'

            # if cocoapods version == 1.5
            config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
            config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do, maybe it's not the best solution but it works:

```
pod_version = `pod --version` # using backticks you can execute shell commands and get result

pod_version ["\n"] = "" # here remove the trailing \n

if pod_version === '1.5.0'
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```